# Create list by repeated application of function

Tags: python, list

I want this:

```
[foo() for _ in xrange (100)]
```

but beautifuller. ?

Comment: Coming from a C# background, that's pretty beautiful. It's beautifuller than `Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(x => foo());`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid you're not gonna get it any prettier than that in Python, except that some people would advise against `_` for an "anonymous" variable. This is the Pythonic idiom for doing what you want.

(The `_` can be considered confusing to novices because it can be mistaken for special syntax. I use it, but only in the "expert parts" of my code. I also encounter it more and more often, but opinion still seems a bit divided on this one.)

Comment: I thought `_` was the pythonic name for an unused variable?

Comment: @Davy8: it seems not everyone agrees; @Sven Marnach got two upvotes went he told me [not to use `_` this way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384570/whats-the-shortest-way-to-count-the-number-of-items-in-a-generator-iterator).

Comment: One advantage of using `_` is that it will prevent PyLint from complaining about an unused variable. I think any variable name starting with `_` will work.

Comment: I personally prefer something like `ignored` or `_ignored`, since that actually says ignored in the name of the ignored variable.

Answer (score 8):

You can write a generator `repeat` like this:

```
def repeat(times, func, *args, **kwargs):
    for _ in xrange(times):
        yield func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then:

```
list(repeat(100, foo))
```

It also accepts arguments to be passed on to the function, so you can:

```
from random import randint
list(repeat(100, randint, 1, 100))   # 100 random ints between 1 and 100
```

Since it's a generator, you can pipe it into any kind of iterable, be it a `list` (as here) or a `tuple` or a `set`, or use it in a comprehension or a loop.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your definition of "beautifuller", you may prefer this:

`map(lambda x: foo(), xrange(100))`

Although what you have already is much nicer IMO.

Comment: if you have to use `lambda`, `map()` is (well, by most everyone I've heard an opinion from) considered less pythonic than the equivalent list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what it does, you can make `foo()` a generator.

Comment: in my case (foo being a simple function that returns different unparameterized results on each call), making it a generator seems to be overkill.

Answer (score 2):

Your list comprehension is already beatiful and effective but if you need several options to do the same things then i think you can use map here. In case you need to call a certain function the specified number of times use:

```
# in case your func looks like
def func():
    # do something
#then
map(func(), xrange(numberOfTimes))
```

In case your function need value from range then you can use map with lambda:

```
# in case your func looks like
def func(value):
    # do something with value
#then
map(lambda val: func(val), xrange(numberOfTimes))
```

Or in case you need to use data from several lists of the same length:

```
# in case your func looks like
def func(value1, value2):
    # do something with values
#then
map(lambda val: func(*val), zip(xrange(10), xrange(10,20)))
```

And so on...

Answer (score 1):

In case `foo()` always returns the same result, you could use

```
[foo()]*100
```

This has the advantage that `foo()` is only called once.

Edit: As @larsmans points out this only makes sense though if `foo()` returns an *immutable* result.

In all other cases, your solution is fine!

Comment: But if `foo` returns mutable results, even if they compare equal by `==`, this blows up in your face.

Comment: this is just wrong as `foo()` is called only once, as opposed to 100 calls in OP: `[randint(1,100)]*5` gives `[26, 26, 26, 26, 26]`

Comment: That's why I pointed out that `foo()` has to always return the same result -- `randint()` clearly does not do that.