# How many leading entries from a list are found in another list

Tags: python, list, count

I am using Python 3 and I have this problem:

```
ListA = [38,40,27,11,1,5,22,7,47,3,11]
ListB = [12,16,38,5,40,27,3]
```

I need to count how many times in a row any numbers from `ListB` appeared in `ListA`.
The output, in this case, should be `3`.
Because 38, 40 and 27 are numbers that are in `ListB`, and are first 3 numbers in `ListA`.

In case of no matches (if the *first number* in `ListA` is not in `ListB`), the output should be: `0`.

Comment: Output should be 1, because B doesnt have 30, if it was A=[12,12,30,14,12] and B=[12], output should be 2

Comment: yes I got it now, I misunderstood the question at first glance.

Comment: This question is unclear. How do you calculate `3`? Why are 38 / 40 / 27 in  scope but not 5 / 3 ?

Comment: Because numbers 11 and 1 are not in ListB, and i want to get result of how many times -in a row- any numbers from ListB showed in ListA

Comment: do you want to find maximum times a number appeared in a row ? ` A =[12,12,15,12,12,12]` and `B = [12]` ans is 3 or ...ans should be 2 because 12 appears two times consecutively.

Comment: No, i just want to find how many times in a row numbers from ListB apeard in ListA, starting from ListA[0:]. In that case that you gave, output should be 2, yes!

Comment: Please amend your question with the clarifications / examples you provided in your comments.

Comment: @planetmaker someone edited my question, I typed exacly what i wanted b4

Comment: Well, neither edit really made the question clearer to me. From the accepted answer, you are looking for *how many leading entries from ListA are found in ListB*. Is that correct? Thus you start to look through listA at the start. You go and look whether that item is in listB. And then you continue towards the end of listA and stop when you hit an element in A which you do not find in listB.

That problem is not well explained so far, IMHO :) Especially that you are looking only at the start of listA and stop iteration when you find a non-match

Comment: Ok, look. I have main list where i put numbers - ListA. Than i have another list, which is fixed (i cannot change it). My goal is to find how many times in a row i entered numbers that are in the second, unchangable list, ListB. So, in order for accepted answer to work, i wrote formula: ListA.insert(0,input("insert new number") because when i enter new number, it puts it at the beginning of the ListA. Hope i clarified things now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
ListA =[38,40,27,11,1,5,22,7,47,3,11]
ListB = [12,16,38,5,40,27,3]

count = 0
for item_a in ListA:
    if item_a in ListB:
        count += 1
    else:
        break

print(count)  
#  3
```

It only increases the counter if the element is present at front of `ListA` and found in `ListB` else breaks out of loop.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
counter = 0
for value in A:
    if value in B:
        counter += 1
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

A very concise way of doing this would be by using [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) function:

```
from itertools import takewhile

ListA = [38,40,27,11,1,5,22,7,47,3,11]
ListB = [12,16,38,5,40,27,3]

sum(1 for _ in takewhile(ListB.__contains__, ListA))
# 3
```

`takewhile` will take items from `ListA` as long as they are contained in `ListB` (38,40,27). And the [`sum(1 for _ in <iterable>)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5384573/7851470) will simply count them.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `ListB` to a set first for efficient membership lookup:

```
setB = set(ListB)
for count, a in enumerate(ListA):
    if a not in setB:
        break
else:
    count = len(ListA)
```

With your sample input, `count` would become: 3