# Length of timeline() of Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, twitterapi-python, twarc2

I am trying to get all tweets from a specific user:

```
def get_all_tweets(user_id, DEBUG):
    # Your bearer token here
    t = Twarc2(bearer_token="blah")

    # Initialize a list to hold all the tweepy Tweets
    alltweets = []
    new_tweets = {}

    if DEBUG:
        # Debug: read from file
        f = open('tweets_debug.txt',)
        new_tweets = json.load(f)
        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)
    else:
        # make initial request for most recent tweets (3200 is the maximum allowed count)
        new_tweets = t.timeline(user=user_id)
        # save most recent tweets
        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)

    if DEBUG:
        # Debug: write to file
        f = open("tweets_debug.txt", "w")
        f.write(json.dumps(alltweets, indent=2, sort_keys=False))
        f.close()

    # Save the id of the oldest tweet less one
    oldest = str(int(alltweets[-1]['meta']['oldest_id']) - 1)

    # Keep grabbing tweets until there are no tweets left to grab
    while len(dict(new_tweets)) > 0:
        print(f"getting tweets before {oldest}")
        
        # All subsiquent requests use the max_id param to prevent duplicates
        new_tweets = t.timeline(user=user_id,until_id=oldest)
        
        # Save most recent tweets
        alltweets.extend(new_tweets)
        
        # Update the id of the oldest tweet less one
        oldest = str(int(alltweets[-1]['meta']['oldest_id']) - 1)
        
        print(f"...{len(alltweets)} tweets downloaded so far")
    
    res = []
    for tweetlist in alltweets:
        res.extend(tweetlist['data'])
    
    f = open("output.txt", "w")
    f.write(json.dumps(res, indent=2, sort_keys=False))
    f.close()
    
    return res
```

However, `len(dict(new_tweets))` does not work. It always returns 0. `sum(1 for dummy in new_tweets)` also returns 0.

I tried `json.load(new_tweets)` and it does not work as well.

However, `alltweets.extend(new_tweets)` worked properly.

It seems like `timeline()` returns a generator-type value (`<generator object Twarc2._timeline at 0x000001D78B3D8B30>`). Is there any way I can count its length to determine whether there are any more tweets un-grabbed?

Or, is there any way to merge...

```
someList = []
someList.extend(new_tweets)
while len(someList) > 0:
    # blah blah
```

...into one line with `while`?

---

Edit: I tried `print(list(new_tweets))` right before the while loop, and it returns `[]`. It seems like the object is actually **empty**.

Is it because `alltweets.extend(new_tweets)` somehow consumes the new_tweets generator...?

Comment: If `timeline()` is a generator, you should be able to get its length with `sum(1 for dummy in timeline)` .  See [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384570/whats-the-shortest-way-to-count-the-number-of-items-in-a-generator-iterator) for more info.

Comment: @oil_lamp I tried `print("New_Tweets length:" + str(sum(1 for dummy in new_tweets)))` and it is still 0.

Comment: Ur question is good but ur title is very bad.

Comment: @M.Mavini Is it now suitable?

Comment: @TaihouKai I don't know ur needs but atleast looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. This problem can be solved by converting generator to list:

```
new_tweets = list(t.timeline(user=user_id,until_id=oldest))
```