# Trying to create a sliding window that checks for repeats in a DNA sequence

Tags: python, bioinformatics, repeat, biopython, dna-sequence

I'm trying to write a bioinformatics code that will check for certain repeats in a given string of nucleotides. The user inputs a certain patter, and the program outputs how many times something is repeated, or even highlights where they are. I've gotten a good start on it, but could use some help.

Below is my code so far.

```
while True:
    text = 'AGACGCCTGGGAACTGCGGCCGCGGGCTCGCGCTCCTCGCCAGGCCCTGCCGCCGGGCTGCCATCCTTGCCCTGCCATGTCTCGCCGGAAGCCTGCGTCGGGCGGCCTCGCTGCCTCCAGCTCAGCCCCTGCGAGGCAAGCGGTTTTGAGCCGATTCTTCCAGTCTACGGGAAGCCTGAAATCCACCTCCTCCTCCACAGGTGCAGCCGACCAGGTGGACCCTGGCGCTgcagcggctgcagcggccgcagcggccgcagcgCCCCCAGCGCCCCCAGCTCCCGCCTTCCCGCCCCAGCTGCCGCCGCACATA'
    print ("Input Pattern:")
    pattern = input("")


    def pattern_count(text, pattern):
        count = 0
        for i in range(len(text) - len(pattern) + 1):
            if text[i: i + len(pattern)] == pattern:
                count = count + 1
            return count


    print(pattern_count(text, pattern))
```

The issue lies in in the fact that I can only put the input from the beginning (ex. AGA or AGAC) to get an output. Any help or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use `re.findall`:

```
import re
text = 'AGACGCCTGGGAACTGCGGCCGCGGGCTCGCGCTCCTCGCCAGGCCCTGCCGCCGGGCTGCCATCCTTGCCCTGCCATGTCTCGCCGGAAGCCTGCGTCGGGCGGCCTCGCTGCCTCCAGCTCAGCCCCTGCGAGGCAAGCGGTTTTGAGCCGATTCTTCCAGTCTACGGGAAGCCTGAAATCCACCTCCTCCTCCACAGGTGCAGCCGACCAGGTGGACCCTGGCGCTgcagcggctgcagcggccgcagcggccgcagcgCCCCCAGCGCCCCCAGCTCCCGCCTTCCCGCCCCAGCTGCCGCCGCACATA'
pattern = "CCT"
count = sum(1 for _ in re.findall(pattern, text))
```

The `sum(1 for ...)` is a common pattern to count the number of items, a generator returns. See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384570/whats-the-shortest-way-to-count-the-number-of-items-in-a-generator-iterator).