# Python - check if a generator is empty or not

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to build a function in order to return true if a key already exist in a dict or any subdict that is part of this dict, i found this solution :

```
def gen_dict_extract(key, var):
    if hasattr(var,'iteritems'):
        for k, v in var.iteritems():
            if k == key:
                yield v
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                for result in gen_dict_extract(key, v):
                    yield result
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                for d in v:
                    for result in gen_dict_extract(key, d):
                        yield result
```

but the problem is the result is a generator how to do in order to get true if the key already  exist and false if doesn't 
Thanks

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962485/finding-a-key-recursively-in-a-dictionary

Comment: BTW, that code will only work on Python 2, since `.iteritems` has been renamed to `.items`  in Python 3, the old `.items`, which returned a list has been dropped from Python 3.

Comment: You may find the info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41778581/4014959) useful.

Comment: It would be arguably more straightforward to rewrite this function so it returns a simple True/False value, rather than keeping it as-is and writing an empty-generator-checker.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460836/how-to-lengenerator
One more similar question

Comment: Does you dict only contain simple key-value pairs and subdicts, or does it contain lists too? If you don't need to handle lists that code can be simplified.

Answer (score 2):

you should use the generator with a single `next` call in a try/except block and except a `StopIteration`:

```
gen = gen_dict_extract("foo", "bar")
try:
    gen.next()
except StopIteration:
    print("this generator is empty")
```

note that this method will leave "gen" as a generator that already 'yielded' once so you'll need to create another generator to use it.

the best way to use it, of course is to not *check* whether the generator is empty but handling it's "emptiness" while using it.

Comment: But this will also consume and discard the first element. (Of course, if OP only creates the generator in order to see if it's non-empty without planning to use it afterwards, then that's perfectly okay.)

Comment: A simpler way to do that, without using `try... except`, is to give `next` an appropriate default arg.

Comment: @tobias_k you are right, and I was editing my post to add that explanation while you posted :)