# count successive numbers in python list

Tags: python, list, optimization

I have a list of 0s and 1s and I want to know how often 0 occures successively. I wrote a quick and dirty solution. However, I believe it is slow

For example

```
a = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0]
def duration(a):   
    b = "".join([str(x) for x in a])
    return [len(x) for x in b.split("1") if len(x)>0]
print(duration(a))
```

gives the correct output ([3,3,2]). I am convinced that there is a much faster way of doing it.

Thanks,

glostas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby

[len([*g]) for k, g in groupby(a) if k == 0]

[3, 3, 2]
```

As pointed out in [Óscar López](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58511749/2336654)'s answer, using the syntax `list(g)` is compatible with older versions of python.

```
[len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(a) if k == 0]
```

---

#### `for`

```
result = []
count = 0
something_not_zero = 1
for e in [*a, something_not_zero]:
    if e == 0:
        count += 1
    elif count > 0:
        result.append(count)
        count = 0

result

[3, 3, 2]
```

Comment: `[ sum( 1 for x in g ) for k,g ...` ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7460986/842935

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation on @piRSquared's answer (also using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)). This should work in older versions of Python, too:

```
from itertools import groupby

def duration(a):
    return [len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(a) if k == 0]
```

For example:

```
duration([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0])
=> [3, 3, 2]
```

Comment: Personally, I feel `if not k` for `0` comparisons are weak and error-prone, since many other objects are evaluated `True` which are not zero (`None`, `[]`, `''` etc).

Comment: It'll work with OP's data: "I have a list of 0s and 1s". But you're right, I changed it for clarity.

Comment: Using `list(g)` instead of `[*g]` is fair.  I'll point that out in my answer.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez fair enough