# How to check that Python iterator is finite?

Tags: python, iterator, iterable

Lets say there is a function `return_list_from_iterable` that takes any iterable as an argument.

```
def return_list_from_iterable(iterable):
    if is_finite(iterable): #check if iterator is finite
        return list(iterable)
```

Is there a way to check if iterator is fininite before calling `list(iterable)`, e.g if to pass `itertools.repeat('hello, infinity!')` as an argument then, i guess, something bad can happen while the function is running.

Comment: nope, just `itertools.islice()` the number of elements you want/expect

Comment: Not an absolute dupe, but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460836/how-to-lengenerator)

Comment: If it's a generator of any kind, you won't know until you iterate it to its end. Which is obviously nonsensical. For any non-iterator collection-y thing, you can check its `len()` if it has one.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be trying to turn iterators into lists if you have no idea about their finitude.

Comment: Heck, the answer to "is this iterator finite" might not even be well-defined until it terminates. Consider an iterator that makes decisions based on user input.

Comment: Checking for `len(x)` or `x.__length_hint__()` might be a start but will miss many cases

Comment: This is basically the Halting Problem, so no.

Comment: Thanks you all, guys, for commenting, lot of useful stuff, you really helped!