# How knowing number of images in tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()

Tags: python, keras, data-generation

We can generate image dataset using ImageDataGenerator with tf.data.Dataset.from_generator()method.

```
img_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()
gen = img_gen.flow_from_directory(path)
train_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, ...)
train_set.shuffle(2)
```

Now, I would like to know number of images in train_set, I do this :

```
train_set.samples
```

Error was:

```
AttributeError: 'ShuffleDataset' object has no attribute 'samples'
```

Comment: Since it is a generator, you can not get the length of it's items. Because it does not contain any values.  Unless you call it repeatedly to and count it yourself.

Comment: Here there is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7460986/2423278