# How to measure length of generator sequence (list comp vs generator expression)

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator, list-comprehension, sequences

I have a generator that generates a *finite* sequence. To determine
the length of this sequence I tried these two approaches:

```
 seq_len = sum([1 for _ in euler14_seq(sv)])  # list comp
```

and

```
 seq_len = sum(1 for _ in euler14_seq(sv))    # generator expression
```

`sv` is a constant starting value for the sequence.

I had expected that list comprehension would be slower and the
generator expression faster, but it turns out the other way around.

I assume the first one will be much more memory intensive since it
creates a complete list in memory first - part of the reason I also thought it would be slower.

**My question**: Is this observation generalizable? And is this due to
having two generators involved in the second statement vs the first?

I've looked at these [What's the shortest way to count the number of items in a generator/iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384570/whats-the-shortest-way-to-count-the-number-of-items-in-a-generator-iterator?lq=1), [Length of generator output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393053/length-of-generator-output), and
[Is there any built-in way to get the length of an iterable in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390852/is-there-any-built-in-way-to-get-the-length-of-an-iterable-in-python) and saw some other approaches to measuring the length of a sequence, but I'm specifically curious about the comparison of list comp vs generator expression.

PS: This came up when I decided to solve [Euler Project #14](http://projecteuler.net/problem=14) based on a
question asked on SO yesterday.

(By the way, what's the general feeling regarding use of the `'_'` in
places where variable values are not needed).

This was done with Python 2.7.2 (32-bit) under Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Using '_' is the norm for unwanted vars - it's the common and accepted practice - but I'm afraid the rest I can't help you with.

Comment: There is a fair bit more work setting up the generator. Once the sequence is long enough the generator expression should be faster

Comment: What about `len(list(euler14_seq(sv)))`?  Also, if you're testing performance like this you should say what platform you are testing on.  In particular Python version and OS and possibly hardware information.

Comment: I think that in short, generators introduce a `__call__` overhead (which can be slow in Python) and a listcomp does not, but that's a gut feeling I can't back up with references...

Comment: ... and also that a listcomp's statement is more optimisable as the code executed is static, while a generator can bubble around and pursue other things at will

Comment: @PeterGraham I added some more information about Python version/OS to my post - thanks for suggesting that. I could try `len()` on *both* expressions, but I would expect the result to not change. Also, by applying `list()` to the generator aren't you mostly eliminating the comparison of generator vs list comp?

Comment: @Levon: I was suggesting another way to find the length of a generator.  It's probably not relevant to whether a list comprehension or generator expression is faster.  The difference is that once you have a list `len` is very fast and O(1) while `sum` is likely far slower and O(n)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On this computer, the generator expression becomes faster somewhere between 100,000 and 1,000,000

```
$ python -m timeit "sum(1 for x in xrange(100000))"
10 loops, best of 3: 34.8 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit "sum([1 for x in xrange(100000)])"
10 loops, best of 3: 20.8 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit "sum(1 for x in xrange(1000000))"
10 loops, best of 3: 315 msec per loop
$ python -m timeit "sum([1 for x in xrange(1000000)])"
10 loops, best of 3: 469 msec per loop
```

Comment: I cranked up the value of `sv` to 1000000000, still list comp is faster (25 us/loop vs 30 us/loop) ..

Comment: @Levon, I think the main hit to the LC is the memory allocation. Your's is a lot faster than mine. For a busy web server the tradeoff can become tricky as storing those temporary lists in your precious RAM can be more expensive than the extra cycles used by the generator

Comment: Perhaps, I do have a lot of RAM available. And your point in the comments re setup for the generator is a good one too. Still a bit puzzling. I'll have to play around with this some more. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The following code block should generate the length:

```
>>> gen1 = (x for x in range(10))
>>> len(list(gen1))
10
```

Comment: I didn't want to mix up `len()` vs `sum()` in order to keep the comparison true. And the basic gist of my question is to figure out if "list comp" will always be faster than "generator expressions" in general.

Comment: @Levon take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension

Comment: Thanks .. I'll take a close look at that (just quickly skimmed it)