# How do I find the length of list in generator. (Python)

Tags: python, generator

I have this generator which returns a list of numbers.

```
li=tile_generator(im)
```

I need to find the length of the list "li" as I need to check for a threshold value.
I used `length = sum(1 for i in li)`. It is returning the length of the list but the elements in the generator are exhausted as it is a generator.
I need to return the length without exhausting the elements in the generator.

Comment: This has been answered in great detail a few times on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460836/how-to-lengenerator, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/393053/length-of-generator-output

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.  You can, however, turn it into a list first:

```
li = list(tile_generator(im))
length = len(li)
```

Comment: yes,but my concern is to use generator because i want to free away the elements when read. If i change it to list then i would be having unnecessary memory load.

Comment: My point is that you cannot find the length of a generator without exhausting it.  I can suggest, however, that maybe you are looking for `enumerate()`.  You could say, for example, `for i, item in enumerate(tile_generator(im)):` and put any code you want in there.  Once you are finished in your `for` loop, `i` will be the same as the length of the generator minus one.  If you need the length *before* you use the generator, however, my answer is the only way.