# Number of days between 2 dates, excluding weekends

Tags: python, datetime

How can I calculate number of days between two dates excluding weekends?

Comment: How are you representing the dates?

Comment: do you want also to exclude public holidays?

Answer (score 122):

I think the cleanest solution is to use the numpy function `busday_count`

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

start = dt.date( 2014, 1, 1 )
end = dt.date( 2014, 1, 16 )

days = np.busday_count( start, end )
```

Answer (score 67):

```
>>> from datetime import date,timedelta
>>> fromdate = date(2010,1,1)
>>> todate = date(2010,3,31)
>>> daygenerator = (fromdate + timedelta(x + 1) for x in xrange((todate - fromdate).days))
>>> sum(1 for day in daygenerator if day.weekday() < 5)
63
```

This [creates a generator using a generator expression](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-generator) which [will yield the list of days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060279/iterating-through-a-range-of-dates-in-python) to get from the `fromdate` to `todate`.

We could then create a list from the generator, filtering out weekends using [the `weekday()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday), and the size of the list gives the number of days we want.  However, to save having the whole list in memory which could be a problem if the dates are a long time apart we use another generator expression which filters out weekends but returns 1 instead of each date.  [We can then just add all these 1s together to get the length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390852/is-there-any-built-in-way-to-get-the-length-of-an-iterable-in-python) without having to store the whole list.

Note, if `fromdate == todate` this calculate 0 not 1.

Comment: Your note indicates that this counts up to but not including `todate`.  Just change the xrange expression to `xrange((todate-fromdate).days + 1)`, and that will give you a daygenerator inclusive of `todate`.
Also, just an aside, but since True = 1, your sum expression can simply read (if you care), `sum(day.weekday() < 5 for day in daygenerator)`.  Maybe a bit clever, but this not a terrible idiom for counting the number of things that match a condition.

Answer (score 31):

First import `numpy` as `np`. The function `np.busday_count` counts the number of valid days between two dates, excluding the day of the end date.

If end date is earlier than the begin date, the count will be negative. For more on `np.busday_count` read the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html).

```
import numpy as np
np.busday_count('2018-04-10', '2018-04-11')
```

Note that the function accepts strings, it's not necessary to instantiate `datetime` objects before calling the function.

Also supports specific valid days and option to add holidays as well.

```
import numpy as np
np.busyday_count('2019-01-21','2020-03-28',weekmask=[1,1,1,1,1,0,0],holidays=['2020-01-01'])
```

weekmask format = [Mon,Tue,Wed.....Sat,Sun]

Comment: congratulations to your first post. unfortunately this answer was already provided by the user Ben down below about 3 1/2 years ago. Please read other answers before providing one by yourself to avoid such duplicates

Comment: Make sure your dates are converted to strings if you're pulling your data from a series.  Example df['mydatecol'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').

Comment: For the lazy, use `holidays`: https://pypi.org/project/holidays/

Answer (score 10):

The answers given so far will work, but are highly inefficient if the dates are a large distance apart (due to the loop).

This should work:

```
import datetime

start = datetime.date(2010,1,1)
end = datetime.date(2010,3,31)

daydiff = end.weekday() - start.weekday()

days = ((end-start).days - daydiff) / 7 * 5 + min(daydiff,5) - (max(end.weekday() - 4, 0) % 5)
```

This turns it into whole weeks (which have 5 working days) and then deals with the remaining days.

Comment: b-a undefined, should be end-start?

Comment: Good point - I wrote it with a and b and then changed to meaningful names.  I see you have worked on the edge cases that I may have missed.  I may revisit this if I have time and check it is watertight.

Comment: Note that the @neil's code will fail for Sunday-Thursday intervals. Here is a fix http://stackoverflow.com/a/32698089/1617748 (edit: new answer and link for better formatting)

Comment: @vekerdyb Unfortunately yours isn't working for all cases, either. See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62835010/865695.

Comment: This fails for quite a few test cases. When compared to `numpy` the following cases fail `(datetime(1800, 4, 6), datetime(2023, 4, 16)), (datetime(1800, 4, 6), datetime(2023, 4, 15)), (datetime(2023, 4, 8), datetime(2023, 4, 16)), (datetime(2023, 4, 8), datetime(2023, 4, 15)), (datetime(2023, 4, 9), datetime(2023, 4, 15)), (datetime(2023, 4, 9), datetime(2023, 4, 16))`

Answer (score 10):

The lazy way is to `pip install workdays` to get the python package that does exactly this.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/workdays/

Comment: I am using this package, however it is lacking in other features such as returning the a list of individual dates

Comment: https://github.com/seatgeek/businesstime works well if you want to get days+hours in timedelta form.

Answer (score 7):

So far, I found none of the provided solutions satisfactory. Either there is a dependency to a lib I don't want or there are inefficient looping algorithms or there are algorithms that won't work for all cases. Unfortunately the one provided by @neil did not work sufficiently well. This was corrected by @vekerdyb's answer which unfortunately did not work for all cases, either (pick a Saturday or a Sunday on the same weekend for example...).
So I sat down and tried my best to come up with a solution that is working for all dates entered. It's small and efficient. Feel free to find errors in this one, as well, of course. Beginning and end are inclusive (so Monday-Tuesday in one week are 2 workdays for example).

```
def get_workdays(from_date: datetime, to_date: datetime):
    # if the start date is on a weekend, forward the date to next Monday
    if from_date.weekday() > 4:
        from_date = from_date + timedelta(days=7 - from_date.weekday())
    # if the end date is on a weekend, rewind the date to the previous Friday
    if to_date.weekday() > 4:
        to_date = to_date - timedelta(days=to_date.weekday() - 4)
    if from_date > to_date:
        return 0
    # that makes the difference easy, no remainders etc
    diff_days = (to_date - from_date).days + 1
    weeks = int(diff_days / 7)
    return weeks * 5 + (to_date.weekday() - from_date.weekday()) + 1
```

Comment: I was reading your response for carrying out an exercise like this. If I would like to get the days (Mon-Fri) but excluding the last days, how should be this code reshape, if something needs to be changed?

Comment: error in the last line: `to_date.weekday() - from_date.weekday()` you can get negative value, so period Fri-Mon will give -3, instead of 2. Easy fix: `if to_date.weekday() < from_date.weekday(): remainder = 5 + remainder` where `remainder = (to_date.weekday() - from_date.weekday()) + 1`

Comment: actually there was a need to one more fix, I've added my version in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71977946/1654692

Comment: it fails for 
2023-01-24
2023-04-17

Answer (score 6):

## 1. With using external service to get public holidays/extra work days

Can't thank @Renan enough for introducing this amazing API that I'm now using in my own project. Here's his answer with slight cleaning + tests.

```python
import urllib.request
import json
from typing import Dict

from dateutil import rrule
from datetime import date


WEEKDAY_FRIDAY = 4  # date.weekday() starts with 0


class CountryCalendar(object):

    def __init__(self, special_dates: Dict[date, str]):
        self.special_dates = special_dates

    def is_working_day(self, dt: date):
        date_type = self.special_dates.get(dt)
        if date_type == "extra_working_day":
            return True
        if date_type == "public_holiday":
            return False
        return dt.weekday() <= WEEKDAY_FRIDAY


def load_calendar(
    country: str,
    region: str,
    start_date: date,
    end_date: date
) -> CountryCalendar:
    """
    Access Enrico Service 2.0 JSON
    https://kayaposoft.com/enrico/

    Response format (for country=rus):

    [
        {
            holidayType: "public_holiday",
            date: {
                day: 2,
                month: 1,
                year: 2022,
                dayOfWeek: 7
            },
            name: [
                {lang: "ru", text: "Новогодние каникулы"},
                {lang: "en", text: "New Year’s Holiday"}
            ]
        },
        ...
    ]
    """
    urlstring = (
        f"https://kayaposoft.com/enrico/json/v2.0/"
        f"?action=getHolidaysForDateRange"
        f"&fromDate={start_date:%d-%m-%Y}"
        f"&toDate={end_date:%d-%m-%Y}"
        f"&country={country}"
        f"&region={region}"
        f"&holidayType=all"
    )

    with urllib.request.urlopen(urlstring) as url:
        payload = json.loads(url.read().decode())

    return CountryCalendar({
        date(
            special_date["date"]["year"],
            special_date["date"]["month"],
            special_date["date"]["day"],
        ): special_date["holidayType"]
        for special_date in payload
    })


def count_work_days(
    start_date: date,
    end_date: date,
    country: str,
    region: str,
):
    """
    Get working days specific for country
    using public holidays internet provider
    """
    if start_date > end_date:
        return 0

    try:
        country_calendar = load_calendar(country, region, start_date, end_date)
    except Exception as exc:
        print(f"Error accessing calendar of country: {country}. Exception: {exc}")
        raise

    workdays = 0
    for dt in rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY, dtstart=start_date, until=end_date):
        if country_calendar.is_working_day(dt):
            workdays += 1

    return workdays


def test(test_name: str, start_date: date, end_date: date, expected: int):
    print(f"Running: {test_name}... ", end="")
    params = dict(
        start_date=start_date,
        end_date=end_date,
        country="rus",
        region=""
    )
    assert expected == count_work_days(**params), dict(
        expected=expected,
        actual=count_work_days(**params),
        **params
    )
    print("ok")


# Start on Mon
test("Mon - Mon", date(2022, 4, 4), date(2022, 4, 4), 1)
test("Mon - Tue", date(2022, 4, 4), date(2022, 4, 5), 2)
test("Mon - Wed", date(2022, 4, 4), date(2022, 4, 6), 3)
test("Mon - Thu", date(2022, 4, 4), date(2022, 4, 7), 4)
test("Mon - Fri", date(2022, 4, 4), date(2022, 4, 8), 5)
test("Mon - Sut", date(2022, 4, 4), date(2022, 4, 9), 5)
test("Mon - Sun", date(2022, 4, 4), date(2022, 4, 10), 5)
test("Mon - next Mon", date(2022, 4, 4), date(2022, 4, 11), 6)
test("Mon - next Tue", date(2022, 4, 4), date(2022, 4, 12), 7)


# Start on Fri
test("Fri - Sut", date(2022, 4, 1), date(2022, 4, 2), 1)
test("Fri - Sun", date(2022, 4, 1), date(2022, 4, 3), 1)
test("Fri - Mon", date(2022, 4, 1), date(2022, 4, 4), 2)
test("Fri - Tue", date(2022, 4, 1), date(2022, 4, 5), 3)
test("Fri - Wed", date(2022, 4, 1), date(2022, 4, 6), 4)
test("Fri - Thu", date(2022, 4, 1), date(2022, 4, 7), 5)
test("Fri - next Fri", date(2022, 4, 1), date(2022, 4, 8), 6)
test("Fri - next Sut", date(2022, 4, 1), date(2022, 4, 9), 6)
test("Fri - next Sun", date(2022, 4, 1), date(2022, 4, 10), 6)
test("Fri - next Mon", date(2022, 4, 1), date(2022, 4, 11), 7)


# Some edge cases
test("start > end", date(2022, 4, 2), date(2022, 4, 1), 0)
test("Sut - Sun", date(2022, 4, 2), date(2022, 4, 3), 0)
test("Sut - Mon", date(2022, 4, 2), date(2022, 4, 4), 1)
test("Sut - Fri", date(2022, 4, 2), date(2022, 4, 8), 5)
test("Thu - Fri", date(2022, 3, 31), date(2022, 4, 8), 7)
```

## 2. Simple math: without usage of service for public holidays/extra work days

Even if @Sebastian answer can't be applied in many cases, as it's not considering public holidays and extra working days, I still find it great, as it's do the job without and decided to fix a bug (basically only his last line was changed).

```python
from datetime import date, timedelta


WEEKDAY_FRIDAY = 4  # date.weekday() starts with 0


def count_work_days(start_date: date, end_date: date):
    """
    Math function to get workdays between 2 dates.
    Can be used only as fallback as it doesn't know
    about specific country holidays or extra working days.
    """
    # if the start date is on a weekend, forward the date to next Monday

    if start_date.weekday() > WEEKDAY_FRIDAY:
        start_date = start_date + timedelta(days=7 - start_date.weekday())

    # if the end date is on a weekend, rewind the date to the previous Friday
    if end_date.weekday() > WEEKDAY_FRIDAY:
        end_date = end_date - timedelta(days=end_date.weekday() - WEEKDAY_FRIDAY)

    if start_date > end_date:
        return 0
    # that makes the difference easy, no remainders etc
    diff_days = (end_date - start_date).days + 1
    weeks = int(diff_days / 7)

    remainder = end_date.weekday() - start_date.weekday() + 1

    if remainder != 0 and end_date.weekday() < start_date.weekday():
        remainder = 5 + remainder

    return weeks * 5 + remainder


def test(test_name: str, start_date: date, end_date: date, expected: int):
    print(f"Running: {test_name}... ", end="")
    params = dict(
        start_date=start_date,
        end_date=end_date,
    )
    assert expected == count_work_days(**params), dict(
        expected=expected,
        actual=count_work_days(**params),
        **params
    )
    print("ok")


# Start on Mon
test("Mon - Mon", date(2022, 4, 4), date(2022, 4, 4), 1)
test("Mon - Tue", date(2022, 4, 4), date(2022, 4, 5), 2)
test("Mon - Wed", date(2022, 4, 4), date(2022, 4, 6), 3)
test("Mon - Thu", date(2022, 4, 4), date(2022, 4, 7), 4)
test("Mon - Fri", date(2022, 4, 4), date(2022, 4, 8), 5)
test("Mon - Sut", date(2022, 4, 4), date(2022, 4, 9), 5)
test("Mon - Sun", date(2022, 4, 4), date(2022, 4, 10), 5)
test("Mon - next Mon", date(2022, 4, 4), date(2022, 4, 11), 6)
test("Mon - next Tue", date(2022, 4, 4), date(2022, 4, 12), 7)


# Start on Fri
test("Fri - Sut", date(2022, 4, 1), date(2022, 4, 2), 1)
test("Fri - Sun", date(2022, 4, 1), date(2022, 4, 3), 1)
test("Fri - Mon", date(2022, 4, 1), date(2022, 4, 4), 2)
test("Fri - Tue", date(2022, 4, 1), date(2022, 4, 5), 3)
test("Fri - Wed", date(2022, 4, 1), date(2022, 4, 6), 4)
test("Fri - Thu", date(2022, 4, 1), date(2022, 4, 7), 5)
test("Fri - next Fri", date(2022, 4, 1), date(2022, 4, 8), 6)
test("Fri - next Sut", date(2022, 4, 1), date(2022, 4, 9), 6)
test("Fri - next Sun", date(2022, 4, 1), date(2022, 4, 10), 6)
test("Fri - next Mon", date(2022, 4, 1), date(2022, 4, 11), 7)


# Some edge cases
test("start > end", date(2022, 4, 2), date(2022, 4, 1), 0)
test("Sut - Sun", date(2022, 4, 2), date(2022, 4, 3), 0)
test("Sut - Mon", date(2022, 4, 2), date(2022, 4, 4), 1)
test("Sut - Fri", date(2022, 4, 2), date(2022, 4, 8), 5)
test("Thu - Fri", date(2022, 3, 31), date(2022, 4, 8), 7)
```

Comment: i tested the math function and it works perfectly fine. thank you! upvoted

Answer (score 3):

```
import datetime

# some givens
dateB = datetime.date(2010, 8, 31)
dateA = datetime.date(2010, 7, 8)
delta = datetime.timedelta(1)

# number of days
days = 0

while dateB != dateA:
    #subtract a day
    dateB -= delta

    # if not saturday or sunday, add to count
    if dateB.isoweekday() not in (6, 7):
        days += 1
```

I think something like that should work. I don't have the tools to test it right now.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed Saturday to Sunday same weekend to function.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import date, timedelta

def workdaycount(startdate,enddate):
    if startdate.year != enddate.year:
        raise ValueError("Dates to workdaycount must be during same year")
    if startdate == enddate:
        return int(startdate.weekday() < 5)
    elif (enddate - startdate).days == 1 and enddate.weekday() == 6: # Saturday and Sunday same weekend
        return 0
    first_week_workdays = min(startdate.weekday(), 4) + 1
    last_week_workdays = min(enddate.weekday(), 4) + 1
    workweeks = int(enddate.strftime('%W')) - int(startdate.strftime('%W'))
    return (5 * workweeks)  + last_week_workdays - first_week_workdays + 1

for comment, start,end in (
     ("Two dates same weekend:", date(2010,9,18), date(2010,9,19)),
     ("Same dates during weekend:", date(2010,9,19), date(2010,9,19)),
     ("Same dates during week", date(2010,9,16), date(2010,9,16)),
     ("Dates during same week", date(2010,9,13), date(2010,9,16)),
     ("Dates during following weeks", date(2010,9,7), date(2010,9,16)),
     ("Dates after two weeks", date(2010,9,7), date(2010,9,24)),
     ("Dates from other solution", date(2010,1, 1), date(2010, 3,31))):

    daydiff = end.weekday() - start.weekday()
    days = ((end-start).days - daydiff) / 7 * 5 + min(daydiff,5)
    daygenerator = (start + timedelta(x + 1) for x in xrange((end - start).days))
    gendays = sum(day.weekday() < 5 for day in daygenerator)

    print(comment,start,end,workdaycount(start,end))
    print('Other formula:', days, '. Generator formula: ', gendays)
```

Answer (score 3):

I adapted Dave Webb's answer into a function and added some test cases:

```
import datetime

def weekdays_between(start, end):
    return sum([1 for daydelta in xrange(1, (end - start).days + 1)
                if (start + datetime.timedelta(daydelta)).weekday() < 5])

assert 7 == weekdays_between(
    datetime.date(2014,2,19),
    datetime.date(2014,3,1))

assert 1 == weekdays_between(
    datetime.date(2014,2,19),
    datetime.date(2014,2,20))

assert 2 == weekdays_between(
    datetime.date(2014,2,19),
    datetime.date(2014,2,22))

assert 2 == weekdays_between(
    datetime.date(2014,2,19),
    datetime.date(2014,2,23))

assert 3 == weekdays_between(
    datetime.date(2014,2,19),
    datetime.date(2014,2,24))

assert 1 == weekdays_between(
    datetime.date(2014,2,21),
    datetime.date(2014,2,24))

assert 1 == weekdays_between(
    datetime.date(2014,2,22),
    datetime.date(2014,2,24))

assert 2 == weekdays_between(
    datetime.date(2014,2,23),
    datetime.date(2014,2,25))
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that the @neil's (otherwise great) code will fail for Sunday-Thursday intervals. Here is a fix:

```
def working_days_in_range(from_date, to_date):
    from_weekday = from_date.weekday()
    to_weekday = to_date.weekday()
    # If start date is after Friday, modify it to Monday
    if from_weekday > 4:
        from_weekday = 0
    day_diff = to_weekday - from_weekday
    whole_weeks = ((to_date - from_date).days - day_diff) / 7
    workdays_in_whole_weeks = whole_weeks * 5
    beginning_end_correction = min(day_diff, 5) - (max(to_weekday - 4, 0) % 5)
    working_days = workdays_in_whole_weeks + beginning_end_correction
    # Final sanity check (i.e. if the entire range is weekends)
    return max(0, working_days)
```

Comment: This one doesn't work either for all cases. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62835010/865695.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following foolproof function to get the number of working days between any two given dates:

```py
import datetime

def working_days(start_dt,end_dt):
    num_days = (end_dt -start_dt).days +1
    num_weeks =(num_days)//7
    a=0
    #condition 1
    if end_dt.strftime('%a')=='Sat':
        if start_dt.strftime('%a') != 'Sun':
            a= 1
    #condition 2
    if start_dt.strftime('%a')=='Sun':
        if end_dt.strftime('%a') !='Sat':
            a =1
    #condition 3
    if end_dt.strftime('%a')=='Sun':
        if start_dt.strftime('%a') not in ('Mon','Sun'):
            a =2
    #condition 4        
    if start_dt.weekday() not in (0,6):
        if (start_dt.weekday() -end_dt.weekday()) >=2:
            a =2
    working_days =num_days -(num_weeks*2)-a

    return working_days
```

Usage example:

```py
start_dt = datetime.date(2019,6,5)
end_dt = datetime.date(2019,6,21)

working_days(start_dt,end_dt)
```

Here, both the start date and the end date is included, excluding all the weekends.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: What advantage does this approach have over all the other answers already given?

Comment: This approach is quite efficient and foolproof. It takes into consideration all the possible scenarios and has minimal run time as it doesn't require any loop. Try it out!!

Comment: It's fool-proof until Christmas falls on a Saturday and Monday becomes a non-working day.

Comment: haha @JeffUK yeah that kinda breaks the spell!

Comment: @Sneftel the "advantage", is that some of these answers are already incorrect in my tests. This one too.
Fails for 2023-01-24 - 2023-04-17
Should return 59, not 61

Comment: @AlexM.M. my solution is returning 60 which seems to be right as per the calculation. I'm counting both start and end date if they fall on weekdays.
It seems to me that you not counting the end date and hence expecting 59.
You can simply do -1 if that's the case

Answer (score 3):

Here's something I use for my management scripts, which takes into account holidays, regardless of which country you're in (uses a web service to pull in country-specific holiday data). Needs a bit of efficiency refactoring but besides that, it works.

```
from dateutil import rrule
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

timezone_manila = pytz.timezone('Asia/Manila')

class Holidays(object):
    
    def __init__(self, holidaydata):
        self.holidaydata = holidaydata
        
    def isHoliday(self,dateobj):
        for holiday in self.holidaydata:
            d = datetime(holiday['date']['year'], holiday['date']['month'], holiday['date']['day'], tzinfo=timezone_manila)            
            if d == dateobj:
                return True
        
        return False

def pullHolidays(start, end):
    import urllib.request, json
    urlstring = "https://kayaposoft.com/enrico/json/v2.0/?action=getHolidaysForDateRange&fromDate=%s&toDate=%s&country=phl&region=dc&holidayType=public_holiday" % (start.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"),end.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")) 
    
    with urllib.request.urlopen(urlstring) as url:
        holidaydata = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    
    return Holidays(holidaydata)


def countWorkDays(start, end):
    workdays=0
    holidayData=pullHolidays(start,end)
    for dt in rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY, dtstart=start, until=end):
        if dt.weekday() < 5:
            if holidayData.isHoliday(dt) == False:
                workdays+=1
    
    return workdays
```

Comment: thanks, for the nice API, 1. I personally went with `holidayType=all` to get extra working day - which is common in our country when we work on Sartuday to get additional holiday during work week. 2. I confused with your use of timezone and even `datetime`, as this will work simpler with `date` without need for timezone.

Comment: thanks again, I've added my version in case it's helpful to anyone https://stackoverflow.com/a/71977946/1654692

Answer (score 0):

I tried the top two answers (Dave Webb's and neil's) and for some reason I was getting incorrect answers from both. It might have been an error on my part but I went with an existing library on the basis that it probably had more functionality and was better tested for edge cases:

https://bitbucket.org/shelldweller/python-bizdatetime

Answer (score 0):

This is a function that I implemented for measuring how many working days it takes for code to be integrated across branches. It does not need iterating over the whole intermediate days, as other solutions do, but only for the first week.

This problem can be broken down into two different problems:

1. **Calculating the number of integral weeks in the interval**: for an integral week, the number of weekend days is always 2. This is a trivial integer division: `(todate - fromdate)/7`
2. **Calculating the number of weekend days in the remaining interval**: this can be easily solved with the counting approach (map-reduce like): `sum(map(is_weekend, rem_days))`.

```
def count_working_days(fromdate, todate):
    from datetime import timedelta as td
    def is_weekend(d): return d.weekday() > 4

    # 1st problem
    num_weeks = (todate - fromdate).days/7

    # 2nd problem
    rem_days = (todate - fromdate).days%7
    rem_weekend_days = sum(is_weekend(fromdate + td(days=i+1)) for i in range(rem_days))

    return (todate - fromdate).days - 2*num_weeks - rem_weekend_days
```

And a sample of its working:

```
>>> for i in range(10): latency(datetime.now(), datetime.now() + timedelta(days=i))
...
0    1    1    1    2    3    4    5    6    6
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this package called business-duration in PyPi.

### Example Code:

```
from business_duration import businessDuration

import pandas as pd

import datetime

start = pd.to_datetime("2010-1-1 00:00:00")

end = pd.to_datetime("2010-3-31 00:00:00")

businessDuration(startdate=start,enddate=end,unit='day')
```

> Out[6]: 62.99927083333333

Answer (score 0):

you may use https://pypi.org/project/python-networkdays/
The package has no dependencies, no NumPy or pandas to calculate a date. ;)

```
In [3]: import datetime

In [4]: from networkdays import networkdays

In [5]: HOLIDAYS  = { datetime.date(2020, 12, 25),}

In [6]: days = networkdays.Networkdays(datetime.date(2020, 12, 1),datetime.date(2020, 12, 31), holidays=HOLIDAYS, weekdaysoff={6,7})

In [7]: days.networkdays()
Out[7]:
[datetime.date(2020, 12, 1),
 datetime.date(2020, 12, 2),
 datetime.date(2020, 12, 3),
 datetime.date(2020, 12, 4),
 datetime.date(2020, 12, 7),
 datetime.date(2020, 12, 8),
 datetime.date(2020, 12, 9),
 datetime.date(2020, 12, 10),
 datetime.date(2020, 12, 11),
 datetime.date(2020, 12, 14),
 datetime.date(2020, 12, 15),
 datetime.date(2020, 12, 16),
 datetime.date(2020, 12, 17),
 datetime.date(2020, 12, 18),
 datetime.date(2020, 12, 21),
 datetime.date(2020, 12, 22),
 datetime.date(2020, 12, 23),
 datetime.date(2020, 12, 24),
 datetime.date(2020, 12, 28),
 datetime.date(2020, 12, 29),
 datetime.date(2020, 12, 30),
 datetime.date(2020, 12, 31)]
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3; xrange() is only for Python 2. Based on the answer from Dave Webb and includes code to show the days including weekends

```
import datetime

start_date = datetime.date(2014, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2014, 1, 16)

delta_days = (end_date - start_date).days
delta_days # 13

day_generator = (start_date + datetime.timedelta(x + 1) for x in range((end_date - start_date).days))
delta_days = sum(1 for day in day_generator if day.weekday() < 5)
delta_days # 10
```

Answer (score 0):

For those also wanting to exclude public holidays without manually specifying them, one can use the [`holidays`](https://pypi.org/project/holidays/) package along with `busday_count` from `numpy`.

```py
from datetime import date 

import numpy as np
import holidays

np.busday_count(
    begindates=date(2021, 1, 1),
    enddates=date(2021, 3, 20),
    holidays=list(
        holidays.US(state="CA", years=2021).keys()
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want a `date`, `x` business days away from a known date, you can do

```
import datetime
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BusinessDay
known_date = datetime.date(2022, 6, 7)
x = 7 # 7 business days away

date = known_date - 7 * BusinessDay() # Timestamp('2022-05-27 00:00:00')
```

if you want the series of dates

```
import pandas as pd
date_series  = pd.bdate_range(date, known_date) # DatetimeIndex(['2022-05-27', '2022-05-30', '2022-05-31', '2022-06-01','2022-06-02', '2022-06-03','2022-06-06', '2022-06-07'],dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest this (there is a bug that I fix in the solution of David Webb) that gives 64 instead of 63 days

```
from datetime import date,timedelta
fromdate = date(2010,1,1)
todate = date(2010,3,31)
daygenerator = (fromdate + timedelta(x + 1) for x in xrange((todate - fromdate).days))
sum(1 for day in [fromdate] + list(daygenerator) if day.weekday() < 5)
```

NB: we must add the first date (fromdate) at the top of the days generated to be sure that It'll be considered when excluding weekends

Answer (score 0):

Lets first start with a simple but wrong model: calculating the number of weeks, divide that by seven and multiply by five, so:

```
d0 = date(1958, 3, 25)   # inclusive
d1 = date(2019, 11, 25)  # inclusive
dw = (d1 - d0).days // 7 * 5   # wrong!!
```

here `(d1 - d0).days` gives us the total number of days, and then we divide that by seven, and multiply it by five, so we get a lower bound, since in order add five (working) days, we need to have a full week.

It is however quite a good base, the only thing that we still don't have is the number of working days outside these full weeks. We can determine this by using the [**`.weekday()`** method <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday).

For this there are basically two scenarios. If the weekday of the start date is less than the one of the end date, then this means that we have to add that number of days, but capped with five minus the workday of the start day. This is because if the start week day is for example monday (weekday = 0), then there are at most five workdays, if we start at wednesday, then there are at most three.

Another scenario is where the week day of the end day. That means we did a wraparound that will definitely include a weekend. Then we calculate this with the sum of five minus the weekday we start with plus the weekday of the end date capped by five.

We thus can summarize this to:

So to conclude we add:

```
if d0.weekday() <= d1.weekday():
   extra = max(0, min(5 - d0.weekday(), d1.weekday() - d0.weekday() + 1))
else:
   extra = max(5 - d0.weekday(), 0) + min(d1.weekday() + 1, 5)
```

so the full code is:

```
def workdays(d0: date, d1: date) -> int:
    dw = (d1 - d0).days // 7 * 5
    if d0.weekday() <= d1.weekday():
        return dw + max(0, min(5 - d0.weekday(), d1.weekday() - d0.weekday() + 1))
    else:
        return dw + max(5 - d0.weekday(), 0) + min(d1.weekday() + 1, 5)
```

and that's it. We can test this for several ranges with a simple script:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

ds = date(1958, 3, 25)
dmax = 1000

for dd0 in tqdm(range(dmax+1)):
    d0 = ds + timedelta(days=dd0)
    for dd1 in range(dd0, dmax+1):
        d1 = ds + timedelta(days=dd1)
        dw0 = workdays(d0, d1)
        dw1 = sum((d0 + timedelta(days=dd2)).weekday() < 5 for dd2 in range((d1-d0).days+1))
        assert dw0 == dw1
```

This will thus for a large number of ranges check if our function matches with a brute force approach where we enumerate over all days. The `workdays` function however is far more efficient, since even if the number of weeks is huge, it will only have to make some calculates about the "edges".

Answer (score -1):

My solution is also counting the last day. So if start and end are set to the same weekday then the asnwer will be 1 (eg 17th Oct both). 
If start and end are 2 consecutive weekdays then answer will be 2 (eg for 17th and 18th Oct). 
It counts the whole weeks (in each we will have 2 weekend days) and then check reminder days if they contain weekend days.

```
import datetime

def getWeekdaysNumber(start,end):
    numberOfDays = (end-start).days+1
    numberOfWeeks = numberOfDays // 7
    reminderDays = numberOfDays % 7
    numberOfDays -= numberOfWeeks *2
    if reminderDays:
        #this line is creating a set of weekdays for remainder days where 7 and 0 will be Saturday, 6 and -1 will be Sunday
        weekdays = set(range(end.isoweekday(), end.isoweekday() - reminderDays, -1))
        numberOfDays -= len(weekdays.intersection([7,6,0,-1])
    return numberOfDays
```

usage example:

```
start = date(2018,10,10)
end = date (2018,10,17)
result = getWeekdaysNumber(start,end)`
```