# Adding Business Days to Date Field

Tags: python, mysql, django, date, models

I am trying to add a number of business days to a date field in Django. This is for product ordering where we have different lead times for different products and we want to generated a target date for each product.

for example, product X might take 10 business days to deliver, if this product is ordered on Friday date 01/03/2013 the target date should end up being the Friday 15/03/2013 (it excludes the ordering date as a day).

I have had a look around and there seems to be some python libraries to do this kinda stuff but it all seemed overly complicated. I thought that there would be a fairly simple way to do this.

** EDIT **

I am now using the BusinessHours PyPi package, however seem to be getting some problems.

They give you an example on how to call the package.

```
eg: Class:  BusinessHours(datetime1,datetime2,worktiming=[9 ,18],weekends=[6,7],holidayfile=None)

Class Parameters:
datetime1   - The datetime object with the starting date.
datetime2   - The datetime object with the ending date.
worktiming  - The working office hours . A list containing two values start time and end time
weekends    - The days in a week which have to be considered as weekends sent as a list, 1 for monday ...  7 for sunday.
holidayfile - A file consisting of the predetermined office holidays.Each date starts in a new line and currently must only be in the format dd-mm-yyyy

from BusinessHours import BusinessHours
from datetime import datetime
testing = BusinessHours(datetime(2007,10,15),datetime.now())
print testing.getdays()
```

Using this information I made the below test script

```
from BusinessHours import BusinessHours
from datetime import datetime
holidaytextfile = 'holidays.txt' 

testing = BusinessHours(datetime(2013,02,01),datetime(2013,02,28),worktiming=[9 ,18],weekends=[6,7],holidayfile=holidaytextfile)
print testing.getdays()
```

My holiday file contains the following (just a random business day in Feb)

```
07-02-2013
```

When I run the script I get the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "business_days", line 9, in ?
print testing.getdays()
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/BusinessHours.py", line 63, in getdays
holidate = date(int(year) , int(month) , int(day))
NameError: global name 'date' is not defined
```

This is the section of code from the package.

```
 60             for definedholiday in definedholidays:
 61                 flag=0;
 62                 day , month , year = definedholiday.split('-')
 63                 holidate = date(int(year) , int(month) , int(day))
 64                 for weekend in self.weekends:
 65                      #check if mentioned holiday lies in defined weekend , shouldnt deduct twice
 66                     if(holidate.isoweekday==weekend):
 67                         flag=1;
 68                         break;
```

I appreciate any assistance anybody an give me, my Python version is 2.4.3

Comment: You may have a *much* bigger problem than you realize. Business days not only varies based on weekends (which may not always be 2 days long), but you also have to account for national and religious holidays (which also vary). And if you are doing international business, it gets even more complicated: weekends/holidays on the shipping end, weekends/holidays in transit (e.g. customs and shipping companies), and finally weekends/holidays at the receiving end.

Comment: Hi Peter,luckily this is a small project in which I will have no exposure to overseas markets etc: so I will only be working on local dates and holidays. Lets say for simplicity sake I could just add an extra day or two buffer to the lead times just in case some public holidays land in the block would that make my task easier?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this question?  I believe it might answer yours with a few lines of code.

[python-count-days-ignoring-weekends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3615984/1822062)

Comment: Hi Ramces, thanks for that link, I did not find that question when I was searching. I *think* I may have got something which does what I want, although I'm guessing its very clunky and could be re-written a lot nicer, I'm still a bit of a noob with Python. This is what I came up with (updated in question). Perhaps you would recomend a better way of doing it?

Comment: Well it worked on one of my examples but a few of them it doesn't seem to work , so I am probably doing something wrong somewhere along the line.

Comment: Plus I'm not too sure how I could work in public holidays into this =\

Comment: Hi baz00r, from reading your earlier comments I thought you didn't care about holidays. As far as I know, there isn't a way to do it natively within Python. I did some digging around and came across this library [BusinessHours](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BusinessHours/) on PyPi. All you have to do is set the holidays your company doesn't work/ship on a separate file. It can calculate the business days for you and seems straightforward.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Ramces, My first priority was to get it working with weekends, now that seems to be working okay, I'm going to give it a go with public holidays. I was thinking I could create a model with a date field, and we could manually enter date fields and check if any of these dates fall in the date range (fromdate - todate). Any idea how I could do that, I'm sure there is something out of the datetime library that could do this.

Comment: Also I am checking out the Pypi thing. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I have downloaded and installed the BusinessHours package as per Ramces reccomendation, and I seem to have it working except for a issue with the date module, I think this may be due to my Python version perhaps (2.4.3) and the module being different. Not too sure. I have outlined the problem above. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Hi baz00r, to correct the NameError see where the `date` function is implemented in the package and import it into that module.