# How to find out if there was weekend between days?

Tags: python

I have two data frames. One representing when an order was placed and arrived, while the other one represents the working days of the shop.

Days are taken as days of the year. i.e. 32 = 1th February.

```
orders = DataFrame({'placed':[100,103,104,105,108,109], 'arrived':[103,104,105,106,111,111]})
Out[25]: 
    arrived  placed
0      103     100
1      104     103
2      105     104
3      106     105
4      111     108
5      111     109



calendar = DataFrame({'day':['100','101','102','103','104','105','106','107','108','109','110','111','112','113','114','115','116','117','118','119','120'], 'closed':[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]})

Out[21]: 
    closed  day
0        0  100
1        1  101
2        1  102
3        0  103
4        0  104
5        0  105
6        0  106
7        0  107
8        1  108
9        1  109
10       0  110
11       0  111
12       0  112
13       0  113
14       0  114
15       1  115
16       1  116
17       0  117
18       0  118
19       0  119
20       0  120
```

What i want to do is to compute the difference between placed and arrived

```
x = orders['arrived'] - orders['placed']
Out[24]: 
0    3
1    1
2    1
3    1
4    3
5    2
dtype: int64
```

and subtract one if any day between arrived and placed (included) was a day in which the shop was closed.

i.e. in the first row the order is placed on day 100 and arrived on day 103. the day used are 100, 101, 102, 103. the difference between 103 and 100 is 3. However, since 101 and 102 are days in which the shop is closed I want to subtract 1 for each. That is 3 -1 -1 = 1. And finally append this result on the orders df.

Comment: You don't have a question. In any case, your main problem has existing solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615375/python-count-days-ignoring-weekends

Comment: What have you tried? If you have a list with days the shop is closed it ought to be a matter of just counting them. Do you need to take X-mas, MLK-day or whatever days that make the shop closed into consideration?

Comment: yes I need to consider also bank holidays