# Get the dates by entering the number of days

Tags: python, date, datetime

I was experimenting with something on Python and came across an interesting problem. I would like to enter the number of days and get the last and today's date in the range I specified. BUT, I only want the dates for the business days (Exclusing Holidays and Weekends). For example, I would like to do:

```
previous_days(10)
```

The output would give me the date that was 10 days ago and also today's date:

```
'2017-02-17'    #10-days ago (because the 20th was President's day)
'2017-03-03'    #Today's date
```

This is what I have been doing so far:

```
todaysDate = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")    #outputs 2017-03-03
tenDaysAgo = datetime.strptime(todaysDate, "%Y-%m-%d").date() + timedelta(days=-12)
```

I had to do `-12` to take into account the weekends. But the dates were incorrect this time because of President's day. Is there a library that exists in Python where I can enter the number of days I want and I can get the dates excluding weekends and holidays? If not, is there a more clever way for me to go about solving my issue?

Comment: Module `calendar` may be of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation for a comment...

If DYZ's comment didn't help, take a look at [dateutil](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook-2nd/0596007973/ch03s06.html).

[More Dateutil examples](http://nazarii.com/blog/2013/06/29/calculating-working-days-with-python/)

Other possibilities on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224742/business-days-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615375/python-count-days-ignoring-weekends)