# Django Diff between Dates

Tags: django, datetime, django-admin, datediff

I have a project in django and i am trying to render html to pdf. 
I'm trying to build a table, and i have two varaibles `date1` and `date2` and i need to do a `Diff` between `date1` and `date2`.

If the result is more than `20  woriking days` show `1` if not show `0`

**MY HTML**

```html
                 {% for item in obj %}
                    <tr> 
                        <td>
                            {% if item.date1 - item.date2 > 20 %}
                            1
                            {% else %}
                            0
                            {% endif %}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a method in the model to calculate difference, then use it in the templates/pdf. For example:

```
class SomeView(models.Model):
    # .. fields

     def date_diff(self):
         diff = self.date1 - self.date2  # returns time delta object
         return abs(diff.days)
```

And use it in template:

```
{% for item in obj %}
    <tr> 
        <td>
            {% if item.date_diff > 20 %}
              1
            {% else %}
              0
            {% endif %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: you need to make sure date1 is bigger than date2. Also days does not count working days, Maybe this answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3615984/2696165

Comment: I have updated the answer with `abs` to get positive value regardless which date is bigger.

Comment: yeh it's working , but to do only working days , how can i do?

Comment: You can use this library: https://github.com/ogt/workdays or please use any answer which suits you( shared with my previous comment) :)

Answer (score 1):

you should perform the calculation in the backend and send number of days value while rendering the template

```
difference=item.date1-item.date2
days=difference.days
```

and in template

```
{% if days > 20 %}
   1
{% else %}
   0
{% endif %}
```

Comment: but the `diffenrece.days` count the days, not the working days right?

Comment: for calculating working days specifically, this might help
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26221138/6027876