# Number of hours between two dates, excluding weekend

Tags: python, python-datetime

I want total number of hours between mention dates excluding weekend(Saturday, Sunday).

````
```
start_time = datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 1, 22, 45, 25)
end_time = datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 15, 10, 00, 00)
```
````

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615375/number-of-days-between-2-dates-excluding-weekends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An additional library is needed for my answer ([NumPy](https://numpy.org/))

Key elements:

1. [numpy.busday_count](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html) to count the number of weekdays
2. [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)(1) to omit starting day (to be checked through if-else to count for minutes)
3. [isoweekday](https://pythontic.com/datetime/date/isoweekday)() returns value between 1 and 7, 1 being Monday and 7 Sunday

Steps:

1. Skip the starting and ending days and find valid in-between days. Multiply by 24 (total hours per day)
2. Check if starting day is a weekday and calculate the total hours remaining to end that date
3. Check if the ending day is a weekday and calculate the total hours passed in that day

```py
import datetime
import numpy as np

start_time = datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 1, 22, 45, 25)
end_time = datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 15, 10, 00, 00)
#Step 1.
total_hours=np.busday_count(start_time.date()+datetime.timedelta(1),end_time.date())*24 #already not counting last date
#Step2.
if start_time.isoweekday() in range(1, 6):
    total_hours=total_hours+24-start_time.hour-start_time.minute/60-start_time.second/3600
#Step 3.
if end_time.isoweekday() in range(1, 6):
    total_hours=total_hours+end_time.hour+end_time.minute/60+end_time.second/3600
```

```
print(total_hours)
output: 227.24305555555554
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from BusinessHours import BusinessHours
import datetime

start_time = datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 1, 22, 45, 25)
end_time = datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 15, 10, 00, 00)

hours = BusinessHours(start_time, end_time, worktiming=[9, 18], weekends=[6, 7], holidayfile=None)
print(hours.gethours())
```

This could help you, for more information please refer BusinessHours module in python!

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
busdays = np.busday_count(start_time.date(), end_time.date())
```

Answer (score -1):

I came up with this, it only uses the datetime module:

```
import datetime

def hours_between_dates(start_datetime):

    today_dt = datetime.datetime.now()

    #calculate the total age in hours

    alltime = today_dt - start_datetime

    hour_alltime = alltime.total_seconds() / 3600

    #if the start date is on the weekend the count starts on the next monday

    if start_datetime.weekday() == 5:
        start_datetime += datetime.timedelta(days=2)
    elif start_datetime.weekday() == 6:
        start_datetime += datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    #iteratinng through the days between the start date and the actual date
    #if the day is a weekend day, it subtracts 24 hours from the total time


    while start_datetime.date() != today_dt.date():
        if start_datetime.weekday() == 5 or start_datetime.weekday() == 6:
            hour_alltime -= 24
        start_datetime += datetime.timedelta(days=1)


    return round(hour_alltime, 2)
```