# Get number of passed business day since beginning of month

Tags: python, date, datetime

Is there a way of finding how many business days have passed since the beginning of the month? Taking today 20240212 as an example, 7 (or 8 if you include today) business days have passed since 1st of February.

I did not find a straightforward way to do it.

Comment: It should be `7`, if you exclude today, no? (1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

Comment: @Mozway, correct! changed it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of days between 2 dates, excluding weekends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615375/number-of-days-between-2-dates-excluding-weekends)

Comment: @TylerH, the answer from nozway below helped a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy with [`numpy.busday_count`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html) and [`date.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.replace) to get the first day of the month:

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

today = datetime.today().date()
nb_days = np.busday_count(today.replace(day=1), today)
```

Output: `7`

For a pure python approach, you could loop over the days and only count those with a weekday < 5:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.today().date()
month_start = today.replace(day=1)

nb_days = sum((month_start+timedelta(days=n)).weekday() < 5
              for n in range((today-month_start).days))
```