# find stretches of Trues in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean

Is there a good way to find stretches of Trues in a numpy boolean array? If I have an array like:

```
x = numpy.array([True,True,False,True,True,False,False])
```

Can I get an array of indices like:

```
starts = [0,3]
ends = [1,4]
```

or any other appropriate way to store this information. I know this can be done with some complicated while loops, but I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: This may be of interest to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352425/whats-the-most-pythonic-way-to-identify-consecutive-duplicates-in-a-list

Comment: what are `ends = [1,4]`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham seems that its ends of `True`s

Comment: the starts and ends arrays record the starts and ends of the stretches of Trues. Could also be recorded in like : `stretches = [(0,1),(3,4)]`

Comment: for the record, I'm surprised there are 2 "too broad" close votes. The question seems to be specific and succinct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pad `x` with Falses (one at the beginning and one at the end), and use [np.diff](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html). A "diff" of 1 means transition from False to True, and of -1 means transition from True to False.

The convention is to represent range's end as the index one *after* the last. This example complies with the convention (you can easily use `ends-1` instead of `ends` to get the array in your question):

```
x1 = np.hstack([ [False], x, [False] ])  # padding
d = np.diff(x1.astype(int))
starts = np.where(d == 1)[0]
ends = np.where(d == -1)[0]
starts, ends
=> (array([0, 3]), array([2, 5]))
```