# Validate card numbers using regex python

Tags: python, regex

I have some credit card numbers with me and want to validate them over the below rules.

► It must only consist of digits (0-9)

► It may have digits in groups of 4, separated by one hyphen "-"

► It must NOT have 4 or more consecutive repeated digits

► It may contain exactly digits without any spaces

Input:

- 5123-4567-8912-3456
- 61234-567-8912-3456
- 4123356789123456
- 5133-3367-8912-3456

**Output:**

- Valid
- Invalid  (because the card number is not divided into equal groups of 4)
- Valid
- Invalid (consecutive 33 33digits is repeating  4 times)

I have tried [here](https://regex101.com/r/JKeOVl/1) and it works only if i include hyphen at the end. Can somebody give me a correct reg ex for it.

**Edit:**

Regex Code: `([0-9]{4}-){4}`

Input to be matched `6244-5567-8912-3458`

It doesn't match until I put hyphen at the end.

**Edit**

```
import re
import itertools
text="5133-3367-8912-3456"
print(len(text))

l=[(k, sum(1 for i in g)) for k,g in itertools.groupby(text)]  #To calculate frequency of characters and later we can filter it with the condition v<=3 for checking the concurrency condition

if re.search(r'^[456]+',text) and len(text)==16  and re.search(r'[\d]',text) and all(v<=3 for k,v in l) and bool(re.search(r'\s',text)) is False and bool(re.search(r'[a-z]',text)) is False or( bool(re.search(r'-',text))is True and len(text)==19) :
    print("it passed")

else :
    print("False")
```

Comment: You are on the right track throughout. A bit off though.

Comment: You should mention that dashes are optional explicitly. Is `1234-56789012-3456` valid?

Comment: Yeah i should have mentioned it. No 1234-56789012-3456 is not valid

Comment: Please edit that into your question, especially the test cases you give in the beginning, which are very helpful.

Comment: Added to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is almost correct. It asks for four dash terminated groups of numbers. What you want is three dash-terminated groups, followed by a non-dash-terminated group, or a single blob with no dashes:

```
(?:[0-9]{4}-){3}[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{16}
```

[[Link](https://regex101.com/r/WvwXHN/5)]

I made the group [non-capturing](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups) since you don't need to capture the contents. You can also use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`:

```
(?:\d{4}-?){3}\d{4}
```

[[Link](https://regex101.com/r/WvwXHN/6)]

The validation of consecutive numbers is probably easier to do in a separate step. Once the regex match passes, remove all the dashes:

```
num = num.replace('-', '')
```

Now check for repeated digits using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), something like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6352425/2988730)/[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6352456/2988730):

```
from itertools import groupby

if max(len(list(g)) for _, g in groupby(num)) >= 4:
    print('Invalid: too many repeated digits')
```

**Full Code**

```
from itertools import groupby
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'(?:\d{4}-){3}\d{4}|\d{16}')

def count_consecutive(num):
    return max(len(list(g)) for _, g in groupby(num)

num = '6244-5567-8912-3458'
if not pattern.fullmatch(num) or count_consecutive(num.replace('-', '')) >= 4:
    print('Failed')
else:
   print('Success')
```

Comment: Dash is optional between group.

Comment: We cannot directly remove dashes in between because if we remove in suppose one of the case 61234-567-8912-3456 it will become valid and we cannot have a group of more than 4 digits.

Comment: @codaholic. You remove the dashes *after* you validate the string

Comment: @Toto. Fixed. Thanks for the catch

Comment: @codaholic. I posted the full sequence so you could see how it works.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for your solution i accepted the ans. Just a small doubt if i use (?:[0-9]{4}-){3}[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{16} with string 4143-4672-8798-2968-2968 it will match and returns true until the 4th group.what if i want to mark such type of cases invalid in the same reg.Although i solved my problem by validating this type of case at the starting of the program and just curious to know how will you solve with reg ex.

Comment: @codaholic. If you look carefully, I use `fullmatch`, not `match` on the pattern for this exact reason: https://regex101.com/r/WvwXHN/7. You do not need any additional validation beyond the regex.

Comment: Yes i saw that and for validation suppose if you use bool(re.search(r'(?:[0-9]{4}-){3}[0-9]{4}',4143-4672-8798-2968-2968)) it will always be true so it will fail my validation

Answer (score 6):

My solution has a 2-step logic. The reason you can not do this in one go, has to do with the limitations of python's re. We'll save that for later. If you're interested, look at **Addendum 1**.

2 steps: the first step will check if the '-' are in the right place, while the second one will check if there are not 4 consecutive equal numbers.

I will start with the 2nd step, the most memory-consuming one: a regex that checks if there are no consecutive 4 numbers. The following regex will do:

```
((\d)(?!\2{3})){16}
```

Explanation:

```
(                       # group 1 start
  (\d)                  # group 2: match a digit
  (?!\2{3})             # negative lookahead: not 3 times group 2
){16}                   # repeat that 16 times.
```

look at [example 1](https://regex101.com/r/e7LUJt/1)

The first step would be matching groups of 4 digits, eventually separated by '-' (look at [example 2](https://regex101.com/r/XJsoCv/2)) The problem to solve here, is to make sure that if first and second group digits is separated by a '-', then all groups need to be separated by a '-'. We manage to do that by using a backreference to group 2 in the next regex.

```
(\d{4})(-?)(\d{4})(\2\d{4}){2}
```

Explanation:

```
(\d{4})                 # starting 4 digits
(-?)                    # group 2 contains a '-' or not
(\d{4})                 # 2nd group of 4 digits
(\2\d{4}){2}            # last 2 groups, starting with a backreference
                        # to group 2 ( a '-' or not)
```

Example program:

```
 import re

 pattern1 = r"(\d{4})(-?)(\d{4})(\2\d{4}){2}"
 pattern2 = r"((\d)(?!\2{3})){16}"

 tests = ["5123-4567-8912-3456"]

 for elt in tests:
     if re.match( pattern1, elt):
         print "example has dashes in correct place"
         elt = elt.replace("-", "")
         if re.match(pattern2, elt):
             print "...and has the right numbers."
```

**Addendum:**
Now for desert. I've put a regex together to do this in one go. Let's think about what is needed for every digit depending on its position in a group:

- 1st digit: followed by 3 digits
- 2nd digit: followed by 3 digits OR digit, digit, dash, digit
- 3rd digit: followed by 3 digits OR digit, dash, digit, digit
- 4th digit: followed by 3 digits OR dash, digit, digit, digit

So, for the lookahead we used in example 1, we need to present for each digit all possibilities of follow-ups. Let's have a look at a pattern for a group of 4 digits:

```
(
  (\d)             # the digit at hand
  (?!              # negative lookahead
   \2{3}           # digit, digit, digit
  |\2{2}-\2        # OR digit, digit, dash, digit
  |\2-\2{2}        # OR digit, dash, digit, digit
  |-\2{3}          # OR dash, digit, digit, digit
  )
){4}               # 4 times, for each digit in a group of 4
```

We would like to expand that to 16 digits of course. We need to define if it's possible to add '-' before the digit. A simple `-?` won't do, because a creditcard doesn't start with a dash. Let's use alternation:

```
(?                 # if
  (?<=\d{4})       # lookbehind: there are 4 preceding digits
  -?               # then: '-' or not
  |                # else: nothing
)
```

Combined, this brings us to:

```
\b((?(?<=\d{4})-?|)(\d)(?!\2{3}|\2{2}-\2|\2-\2{2}|-\2{3})){16}\b
```

Look at [example 3](https://regex101.com/r/e7LUJt/6). We need the \b on both sides because we want to make sure that, whenever the match succeeds, it matches the `complete` string.

Let's be fair: one has its doubts if this is the way to go. On the upside, we have a valid reason for doing it in 2 steps now: python's standard re doesn't support conditionals and what not. You can workaround this, by using a replacement. Or switch programming language. ;-)

**Addendum 2:** People asked me where the `16` comes from in [example 3](https://regex101.com/r/e7LUJt/6). Isn't it true that the complete string can be 19 characters long? The reason is whenever the inner regex (group 1) matches once, it matches with either `[0-9]` or `-[0-9]`. That match has to succeed exactly 16 times.

Comment: No digits repeated more than four times.

Comment: Unless you show how to apply these, they are not of much use on their own.

Comment: @MarcLambrichs. Your first example does not take account of hyphens.

Comment: @ekhumoro True. The reason is that with a lookahead, it's difficult to match 3 follow up digits, because you don't know if you have to look at the following 3 or 4 characters. It's a simpler solution to check if the second regex matches first, then substitute all '-' and match with the first regex.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I beg to differ. But thank you for your downvote.

Comment: @MarcLambrichs. Your last comment indicates that you at least have to explain how to use them. I have removed my downvote because those regexes are pretty cool.

Comment: Hold your horses. My python is rusty.

Comment: @MarcLambrichs. I know that. But your answer should explain that the first example won't work without pre-processing the input.

Comment: Fair enough. Will do.

Comment: This is a neat excercise in regex :)

Comment: @ekhumoro At last I've added a valid reason for doing it in 2 steps. It can be done in one go, however, python's re is the party crasher.

Comment: @MarcLambrichs. Actually, python's re does support condtionals, with its "yes/no" expression: `(?(id/name)yes-pattern|no-pattern)`. This can be combined with the "null" expression `(?!)` to terminate patterns that would otherwise match. I don't know whether this would help in your examples, though. If I have time, maybe I will have a look and see if I can find some alternative solutions.

Comment: @ekhumoro Lookbehind as a conditional is the problem. A change is gonna come: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/

Comment: @MarcLambrichs. There doesn't seem to be much chance of that becoming part of the std lib at the moment. It's been discussed several times, and nothing has ever come of it. Personally, I think regex is already far too bloated with features most people will never need. It would be much better to fix the current re module and add a few key missing features. Simple Is Better Than Complex.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you really want/need to use *regex*, this task can be solved by simple python code like this:

```
import itertools
card = "5133-3467-8912-.456"

# Check if hyphens are ok
if (len(card.split('-')) == 1 and len(card) == 16) or (len(card.split('-')) == 4 and all(len(i) == 4 for i in card.split("-"))):
    # Remove all hyphens (if any)
    card = card.replace("-", "")
    try:
        # Check if numbers only
        int(card)
        # Check if more than 3 repeated digits
        if max(len(list(g)) for _, g in itertools.groupby(card)) > 3:
            print("Failed: 4+ repeated digits")
        else:
            print("Passed")
    except ValueError as e:
        print("Failed: non-digit characters")
else:
    print("Failed: bad hyphens or length")
```

Comment: This is arguably not simpler than regex, but I do agree that plugging regex into everything indiscriminately is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is:

```
(?:\d{4}[ \-]?){3}\d{4}
```

this covers all possible scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Statement:**

1. It must start with a 4,5 or 6
2. It must contain exactly 16 digits // Remove hyphen and calculate length
3. it must only consist of digits (0-9)
4. It may have digits in groups of 4, separated by one hyphen "-"

Regular Expression:

```
^(4|5|6)[1-9]{3}-?[1-9]{4}-?[1-9]{4}-?[1-9]{4}$
```

- It must NOT use any alphabet (no non-numeric data)

Regular Expression:

```
[a-zA-z]
```

- It must NOT have 4 or more consecutive repeated digits

Regular Expression:

```
(\d)\1{3,}
```

Full Code:

```
import re

new_cc=str(input())
#### to check the total lengt
without_hyp=new_cc.replace("-","")
###check for starting with 4,5 or 6 and {1234}: 4 digits within each group
match=re.search(r"^(4|5|6)[1-9]{3}-?[1-9]{4}-?[1-9]{4}-?[1-9]{4}$",str(new_cc))
### check for alphabet characters
nomatch=re.search(r"[a-zA-z]",str(new_cc))
##check for repetative numbers
con=re.search(r"(\d)\1{3,}",str(without_hyp))

if nomatch == None:
        if match != None:
                if len(new_cc.replace("-","")) == 16:
                        if match.group(0):
                                if con == None:
                                        print('Valid')
                                else:
                                        print('Invalid')
                        else:
                                print('Invalid')
                else:
                        print('Invalid')
        else:
                print('Invalid')
else:
        print('Invalid')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def check_first_number(digit):
   if digit >=4 and digit <=6 :
      return 1
   else:
     return 0

def count_digits_per_group(number):
   new_list = number.split("-")
   count_list = list(map(lambda a : len(a),new_list))
   final_count = list(filter(lambda a : a == 4,count_list))
   return final_count

def number_count(number):
   count = 0
   for n in number:
          if n != '-':
             count = count + 1
   return count


def consecutive_repeated_digits(number):
   number_list = "".join(number.split("-"))
   for i in range(len(number_list)):
        try:
           if (number_list[i] == number_list[i+1]):
            if (number_list[i+1] == number_list[i+2]):
                if (number_list[i+2] == number_list[i+3]):
                    return False
        except IndexError:
           pass
   return True
   

numbers = []

n =  int(input())
for i in range(n):
    number = input()
    numbers.append(number)

outputs = []
group = 0

for number in numbers: 

  #Reset group value
  group = 0

  #If Number is sperated by -
  if (number.count("-") > 0):
    group = 1

  if (group == 0):  
    if (check_first_number(int(number[0])) == 0):
        outputs.append("Invalid")
        continue
            
    if (number_count(number) != 16):
        outputs.append("Invalid")
        continue
    
    if (number.isdigit() == False):
        outputs.append("Invalid")
        continue

 if (group == 1):
    
    if (number.count("-") != 3):
        outputs.append("Invalid")
        continue

    if (sum(count_digits_per_group(number)) != 16):
        outputs.append("Invalid")
        continue

if (consecutive_repeated_digits(number) != True):
    outputs.append("Invalid")
    continue


#IF ALL OK
outputs.append("Valid")



#Diplay Result 
for output in outputs:
   print(output)
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a regex validation at all..

Comment: And it's filled with syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

my solution with `regex` and `assert`:

```py
import re

for _ in range(int(input())):
    CC = input()
    try:
        assert re.fullmatch(r'[456]\d{3}(-|)\d{4}(-|)\d{4}(-|)\d{4}',CC)
        assert not(re.search(r'(\d)\1{3,}',CC.replace("-","")))
        
    except AssertionError:
        print('Invalid')
    else:
        print('Valid')
```

Answer (score 0):

2 stages

first stage the 4 or more consecutive digits

seconds stage the rest:

```
N = int(input())
regex1 = re.compile(r'(\d)\1\1\1')
regex2 = re.compile(r'^[456]\d{3}[-]?\d{4}[-]?\d{4}[-]?\d{4}$')
for _ in range(N):
    num = input()
    onlydigits = "".join([x for x in list(num) if x.isdigit()])
    m = regex1.search(onlydigits)
    if m:
        print("Invalid")
        continue
    m = regex2.search(num)
    if m:
        print("Valid")
    else:
        print("Invalid")
```