# A pythonic way to delete successive duplicates of only one element in a list

Tags: python

I know there are many other similar questions posted, but there is a difference in mine that makes it unsolvable with their answers.

I have several lists of characters that may have multiple consecutive spaces, of which I need to keep only one. Repetitions of any other character should remain. I did it in the following way:

```
myList = ['o', 'e', 'i', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'l', 'k', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'j', 'u']
myList_copy = [myList[0]]

for i in range(1, len(myList):
    if not(myList[i] == ' ' and myList[i-1] == ' '):
        myList_copy.append(myList[i])
```

which successfully gives me

```
['o', 'e', 'i', ' ', 'l', 'k', ' ', 'j', 'u', ' ']
```

I don't really think this is a very good, fast way to do it.

I have seen posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352425/whats-the-most-pythonic-way-to-identify-consecutive-duplicates-in-a-list/6352456) (and others) which have similar questions. However, see that I actually need to remove only repeated spaces. Maybe what I need help with is using groupby to do this, but that's why the new post.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your data are strings, or are they really lists of strings?

Comment: You’re probably going to get awkward answers because your inputs are lists of characters.  Try operating on strings instead.  `re.sub` and such are much more obvious solutions then.

Comment: @AMC Well, I'm actually decoding closed captions, each character has a hexadecimal representation. I originally used a list because of other operations I had to do, but maybe this could be a good place to reconsider the convenience of doing all operations on strings.

Comment: @roippi Thank you very much. Regular expressions have helped me a lot in the past. I'm considering doing all operations on strings now. See previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another *simple?* way to do it:

1. Join each item in the `myList` to create a string
2. Split the string by whitespace
3. Join with a space
4. Convert the string into a list

```
myList = ['o', 'e', 'i', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'l', 'k', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'j', 'u']

new = list(' '.join(''.join(myList).split()))
print(new)
```

```
['o', 'e', 'i', ' ', 'l', 'k', ' ', 'j', 'u']
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes,Using `groupby` is a good idea:

```
import itertools

myList = ['o', 'e', 'i', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'l', 'k', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'j', 'u']
result = [key for key,group in itertools.groupby(myList)])

# ['o', 'e', 'i', ' ', 'l', 'k', ' ', 'j', 'u']
```

If you want to get another elements also duplicate,you can use this:

```
myList = ['o', 'e', 'i', 'i' , ' ', ' ', ' ', 'l', 'k', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'j', 'u']
result = []
for key,group in itertools.groupby(myList):
    if key != ' ': # ' 'string
        for j in group:
            result.append(j)
    else: result.append(key)
print(result)
```

Comment: The thing is that this method deletes repetitions of other characters, which should actually remain.

Comment: @TheSprinter ignore your requirements.I edit my post.

Comment: Okay, I have been reading about groupby since I started trying to find an answer to this. I'll try to put this in my own words to see if I understand correctly. The inner for-loop is actually going through the repetitions of each character that's not a space and appending them. When a space is found, it appends the key, which is unique. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @TheSprinter Yes,You got it.

Answer (score 1):

this is the same as yours but in one line

```
myList_copy = [myList[x] for x in range(len(myList)) if not(myList[x] == ' ' and myList[x-1] == ' ')]
```

Comment: Well, yes, that is indeed more pythonic. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

How about using numpy?
Try this code.

```
import numpy as np
myList = ['o', 'e', 'i', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'l', 'k', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'j', 'u']
myList = np.array(myList)
myList = [myList[0]] + list(myList[1:][~((myList[1:] == myList[:-1]) & (myList[1:] == ' '))])
print(myList)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Please excuse my ignorance. I haven't used numpy yet. Can you explain the ~ and the & operators?

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip in a list comprehension to compare each character with the previous one and exclude spaces that are preceded by another space:

```
myList = [ c for p,c in zip([""]+myList,myList) if (p,c) != (' ',' ') ]
```

same approach can be used on a string

```
myList = [ c for p,c in zip("."+myString, myString) if (p,c) != (' ',' ') ]
```

but split() would probably be more concise if you have a string and want a string as output:

```
myString = " ".join(myString.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using a pandas Series and shifting the results?

```
import pandas as pd
serie = pd.Series(['o', 'e', 'i', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'l', 'k', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'j', 'u'])
index = ~(serie == serie.shift(1))
serie = serie[index]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it with other lists and realized it also deleted repetitions of other characters, but those should remain. Nevertheless, this would be a good moment to see how pandas can help me in other operations I'm doing.