# How to get the length of an itertools.product?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am using `itertools` to run a numerical simulation iterating over all possible combinations of my input parameters. In the example below, I have two parameters and six possible combinations:

```
import itertools

x = [0, 1]
y = [100, 200, 300]

myprod = itertools.product(x, y)

for p in myprod:
    print p[0], p[1]
    # run myfunction using p[0] as the value of x and p[1] as the value of y
```

How can I get the size of `myprod` (six, in the example)? I'd need to print this before the `for` loop starts.

I understand `myprod` is not a list. I can calculate `len(list(myprod))`, but this consumes the iterator so the `for` loop no longer works.

I tried:

```
myprod2=copy.deepcopy(myprod)
mylength = len(list(myprod2))
```

but this doesn't work, either. I could do:

```
myprod2=itertools.product(x,y)
mylength = len(list(myprod2))
```

but it's hardly elegant and pythonic!

Comment: Getting the length of an iterator doesn't make sense, and kind of spoils the point of using one! You *could* work it out, though... *"this uses up (what is the proper term?)"* - *"consumes"*, generally.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any built-in way to get the length of an iterable in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390852/is-there-any-built-in-way-to-get-the-length-of-an-iterable-in-python)

Comment: well, it does make a lot of sense in my specific case because (for reasons too long to explain here) I need to get the total number of combinations BEFORE the for loop starts

Comment: But *in general*, as iterators aren't necessarily finite, you can't find out the length without consuming them.

Comment: Sure, but what would you recommend for my specific case, in which my iterator is always finite? Would you recommend using something other than itertools?

Comment: Also, why does the deep copy not work?

Comment: Because the `deepcopy` process still consumes the iterator, it doesn't create another one. You could use [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) to *"copy"* an iterator but, as you're consuming it all up-front, you already lost the memory benefits straight away (see the notes on that function in the docs).

Answer (score 18):

To implement [Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32074568/3001761) for an arbitrary number of source iterables, combining [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [`mul`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul):

```
>>> import functools, itertools, operator
>>> iters = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> functools.reduce(operator.mul, map(len, iters), 1)
27
>>> len(list(itertools.product(*iters)))
27
```

Note that this will not work if your source iterables are themselves iterators, rather than sequences, for the same reason your initial attempts to get the length of the `itertools.product` failed. Python generally and `itertools` specifically can work in a memory-efficient way with iterators of any length (including infinite!) so finding out lengths up-front isn't really a case it was designed to deal with.

Answer (score 11):

While this doesn't answer the question directly, very often we want to find the length of generators to estimate the progress/runtime.

For this, do consider using `tqdm`'s (version >= 4.42.0) wrappers around generator functions that don't forget the lengths of iterators (`tqdm` is a progressbar library). E.g.,

```
from tqdm.contrib.itertools import product
from time import sleep
for i, j in product(range(3), range(4)):
    sleep(1)
```

will show a progress bar. The length of the product is shown as the `total` of the `tqdm` object (e.g.., the `6` in `3/6 [00:03<00:03]` shown).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
mylength = len(x) * len(y)
```

Comment: less convenient in my specific case, because I don't have two inputs but many many more

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous but it's still just the product of the lengths of the source iterables (`functools.reduce(operator.mul, map(len, iters), 1)` in Python 3.x).

Comment: I'm down-voting this because it doesn't answer the question. For example, I have a program that passes around an itertools.product. This clever trick won't work for that.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution I used:

```
import itertools

param = (('a', 'b'), (1, 2)) # a list of lists

# Calculate all combinations
combinations = itertools.product(*param)

# Calculate number of combinations
total_combinations = 1
for i in param:
    total_combinations = total_combinations * len(i)
```