# Itertools Combinations/Permutations size

Tags: python, python-itertools

Is there anyway to see the len() of an itertools.Combination or other object, really, without materializing it to a list?
I can get the cardinality of combs or permutations with the factorials,... but I want something that generalizes.

Thanks

Comment: Note that you can compute some of those likely faster than just iterating over them - for instance a length of `itertools.permutations` can be computed by importing `math.perm` and using the length of the iterable and  the (optional argument) group size passed to `itertools.permutations` without having to iterate over it. Take this for example: `from math import perm; from itertools import permutations as p; letters = "asdfjkl"; group = 3; it = p(letters, group); total = perm(len(letters), group); length = sum(1 for _ in it); length == total;`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For any iterable `it`, you can do:

```
length = sum(1 for ignore in it)
```

That doesn't create a list, so the memory footprint is small.  But for many kinds of iterables, it also *consumes* `it` (for example, if `it` is a generator, it's consumed and can't be restarted; if `it` is a list, it's not consumed).  There is no generally "non-destructive" way to determine the length of an arbitrary iterable.

Also note that the code above will run "forever" if `it` delivers an unbounded sequence of objects.

Comment: This modifies an iterator so that attempting to iterate over it again does nothing. To mitigate that where I'm using itertools, I did:

`import itertools`, then `itCopy = itertools.tee(it)`, then `length = sum(1 for ignore in itCopy)`, then `for i in list(it): ..`

Answer (score 3):

No need to create a list. You can count the number of items in an iterable without storing the entire set:

```
sum(1 for _ in myIterable)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

```
def count_iterable(i):
return sum(1 for e in i)
```

Taken from: [Is there any built-in way to get the length of an iterable in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390852/is-there-any-built-in-way-to-get-the-length-of-an-iterable-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)