# How to Count Total Duplicates in List and Sort Them By Name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking to count the total number of duplicates in a list. Then display in alpha/numeric order the name of the list item along with the number of duplicates.

For example:

-- List 
lst = [blue, green, green, yellow, yellow, yellow, orange, orange, silver, silver, silver, silver]

-- Count Number of Duplicates by X

-- Print List Item & Total Number of Occurrences for Output in Sorted list name Order

Color: blue, Total: 1 
Color: green, Total: 2 
Color: orange, Total: 2 
Color: sliver, Total: 4 
Color: yellow, Total: 3

I am able to complete the above using dictionaries, along with converting the list to a set. My goal is to complete this task all within the list type using the built in functions of Python 3.

Comment: Currently, I am trying to utilize Python as fully as possible without the need of importing modules/libraries. This task is more of a learning experience rather than how can I solve this problem in the quickest / most efficient manner.

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52692658/edit) to include your latest attempts? Good "learning experience" involves having a go, making mistakes and seeing how to fix errors.

Comment: Why are you trying to accomplish this using only lists?

Comment: This is an exercise focused on utilizing list comprehension. From what I understand list have the most flexibility being a mutable structure. I could post my examples utilizing sets and dictionaries but there are already several threads that have very helpful examples. I felt my code would confuse the goal of my post so that is why I omitted them. When you get a chance review Slider's second example. That is exactly what I was looking to accomplish, but was getting lost in many additional methods and modules rather than solving the issue at a very basic level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) with `most_common`:

```
from collections import Counter

lst = ['blue', 'green', 'green', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'orange', 'orange', 'silver', 'silver', 'silver', 'silver']
freq = Counter(lst)
```

Now let's sort by name:

```
print(sorted(freq.most_common(), key=lambda x: x[0])) # [('blue', 1), ('green', 2), ('orange', 2), ('silver', 4), ('yellow', 3)]
```

## Update

Without dictionaries or counter objects, a "manual" way to do this is to sort the list alphabetically first and then compute counts as you iterate. So something like the following:

```
lst = ['blue', 'green', 'green', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'orange', 'orange', 'silver', 'silver', 'silver', 'silver']
lst.sort()

current_color = lst[0] # assuming lst is not empty
count = 0
for c in lst:
    if c == current_color:
        count += 1
    else:
        print('Color:', current_color, 'Total:', count)
        current_color = c
        count = 1
print('Color:', current_color, ', Total:', count) # print the last color
```

Comment: Counter converts the list into a dictionary, then a list of tuples is printed. I am looking for a solution that maintains the list structure, then uses a method such as .format along with sort/sorted to display the information in the example structure above. I am definitely going the long way here but I am looking for all the flexibility of a mutable list.

Comment: @slashdotblake I see what you mean. I've added a possible solution without using dictionaries. The advantage of the second solution is that it does not use any additional space for a dict. While this is a good exercise, if space is not an issue, I would still encourage you to use a counter object for more readable code in real world applications.

Comment: The second example is exactly what I was looking for to solve this problem. I looked through numerous stackoverflow post and none I could find had such a fundamentally basic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you take a look at **collections** module? **Counter** function will help you to achieve your objective very simply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to combine the entries for the same color.  It produces an iterator of pairs `(key, values)`, where values is a generator for the elements matching `key`.

I use a degenerate `sum` to compute the count of the values, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/390885/8316315), but there are other options.

```
import itertools

lst = "blue green green yellow yellow yellow orange orange silver silver silver silver".split()

groups = sorted(((key, sum(1 for _ in values))
                 for (key, values) in itertools.groupby(lst)))

for color, count in groups:
    print("Color: {}, Total: {}".format(color, count))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This does provide a solution but I was hoping to accomplish it without the need of itertools. This line, sum(1 for _ in values), why are you using the _ ? Is it to ignore the value of each item in the list. Can you explain this a bit further.

Comment: Would you be willing to share a solution without the use of any imported modules?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use high performant counter. A counter is a container that stores elements as dictionary keys, and their counts are stored as dictionary values.

`import collections
a = ["blue", "green", "green", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", "orange", "orange", "silver", "silver", "silver", "silver"]
counter = collections.Counter(a)
colors = counter.keys()
for color in colors:
    print 'Color: %s, Total:  %d' % (color, counter[color])`

Answer (score 0):

As requested using no imports, only thing used here was `str.count` and *list comprehension*

```
lista = [
    'blue', 'green', 'green', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'yellow', 'orange', 
    'orange', 'silver', 'silver', 'silver', 'silver'
]

listb = []
for i in lista:
    if i not in listb:
        listb.append(i)

for i in sorted(listb):
    print('Color: {}, Total: {}'.format(i.ljust(6), lista.count(i)))
```

> ```
> Color: blue  , Total: 1
> Color: green , Total: 2
> Color: orange, Total: 2
> Color: silver, Total: 4
> Color: yellow, Total: 3
> ```

Honestly you don't need many tools to accomplish this, if anything I would have just used `listb = set(lista)` but you said no `set`, I threw in the `.ljust(6)` for fun and makes the output prettier

Comment: Really nice example here using the count function. Appreciate the post. The second list I believe you meant to write, listb = []. Your method and Slider's second method are the basic ways I was looking to resolve this problem. I gave the edge to slider because he computed counts manually which I had wanted to do but slipped my mind.

Comment: @slashdotblake yep typo! glad we were able to assist :)